# Write function utilizing function argument's template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I want to write a function that takes an [Eigen Spline](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/classEigen_1_1Spline.html), which is a templated class

```
Spline<typename _Scalar, int _Dim, int _Degree>
```

Is it possible (and how would I) to write a function *which is not a member function of the Spline class* that accepts a generic Spline and makes use of the _Scalar, _Dim, and _Degree variables? They are public `enum`s and a `typedef`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, write a function template:

```
template <typename T, int DIM, int DEG>
void foo(const Spline<T, DIM, DEG>& spline);
```

Note that I have removed all the names with leading underscores. Those are *reserved names* and it is *undefined behaviour* to use them. It seems Eigen is being naughty in this respect.

Comment: [The developers are aware of this, but they don't care](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=361).

Comment: @Jeff Wow, that doesn't inspire much confidence.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a template function itself:

```
template<typename _Scalar, int _Dim, int _Degree>
void myFunction(Spline<_Scalar, _Dim, _Degree> &spline) {
  // do stuff...
}
```